# Question about Bernoulli Distribution calculation

Tags: statistics, mathematical-physics, statistical-inference, descriptive-statistics

[image]
can sombody explain the above calculation in the red circle marked with "why?"?
I am studying MLE with Bernoulli Distribution, and in the middle of a video clip, the lecturer says $ 1\over{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i$  becomes $ n\bar x $. But I can't see anything like $1\over{n}$ in any of the calculation steps in the picture.

Answer (score 1):

Equations shown involve straightforward application of rules of logarithms.
In the red circle, all he is saying is that the sum_i(x_i) -- showing at the
bottom in the product log(p)*sum_i(x_i)  -- can alternatively be written as
N*average(x_i).

That's it.

Comment: But my question is how it becomes like N*average(x_i)? It looks like I am not understanding rules of logarithms, does it?

Answer (score 0):

Logarithms are not needed here. I think it's pretty clear $$\frac{1}{N}\sum^N_{i=1}x_i = \frac{x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_N}{N} = \overline{x}$$
by the definition of what a mean is ($\overline{x}$ represents the mean of $x$).

Comment: I understand if it was involved in the steps of the calculation, but $1\over{n}$ was not there, so I am trying to know where the $1\over{n}$ comes from.